# Can't connect to "localhost" with SQL Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I want to import a large data model from Powerpivot, so I can apply an efficient formula as an added column. I've installed SQL Server, SSMS and Analysis Services (Visual Studio). SSMS can connect to localhost fine.

However, I want to use Data Tools (Visual Studio) to bring in my data model, so I go to New -> Project -> Import from Powerpivot, to open the Tabular Model Designer. When I choose Workspace server and then specify "localhost" or "localdb" and Test Connection, the test fails, with the message: "Cannot connect to the server. Reason: an error occurred while connecting to the server".

How can SSMS connect to "localhost" but Analysis Services cannot? Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does the SSAS log or Flight Recorder have anything relating to the failed login?

Comment: Sorry I've just looked and I can't find the trace file that the flight recorder produces. I'm new to this sorry

Comment: It's in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSAS15.MSSQLSERVER\OLAP\Log` or similar.  You'll have to path down into it, as that folder is ACL'd for the service only by default and you'll have to grant yourself access.

Comment: I've checked in that location and all that is in there are folders called 80, 90, 110, 130, 140, 150, Client SDK.

I think I need to take a step back as I'm getting confused. Can you please give me a step by step process on how you would load a file from PowerPivot data model into SSMS, in order to add a column in SQL?

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I thought you were upgrading a PowerPivot model to an Analysis Services Tabular model, which is what " Import from Powerpivot" does.  Can you update your question with details about what you are trying to accomplish and exactly what you've done?  IE what are the data sources for the PowerPivot model?  What are you trying to change?

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately it's a solution to an odd problem. Basically I have a huge table (123m rows) to which I want to add a column using the new STRING_AGG function. However my organisation's SQL server is only 2016 version, and it is closed to remote access. So the only option is to download the table to a Powerpivot data model, transfer it to my machine, upload it to a local SQL Server (latest version), and add the column using the STRING_AGG function. I can upgrade it to a tabular model, but I can't interact with it using SQL in order to add the STRING_AGG function.

Comment: Actually I’m probably doing it a stupid way. I can probably transfer the table to my laptop in a different way than in a power pivot file

Comment: Yep.  If you can connect to SQL Server with PowerPivot you can connect with BCP, SSIS, Linked Server, or the SSMS Import Export wizard.